# Meteor with Iron Route PathFor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

When I click on user's name, I want the link to go to their profile page. I am using Meteor with iron router. Here are the defined routes:

```
Router.route('/', { name: 'JobsList'}); //homepage with all users

//this is where the user's profile is located and works:
Router.route('/company/:_id/', {
 name: 'CompanyPage',
 data: function() { return Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id); }
});

//this page shows all users with url that works:
Router.route('/companies/', {name: 'CompaniesList'});
```

I get the incorrect link when I hover over the user's name on the homepage but I get the correct link when I hover their name on the '/companies/' page. In order to generate the link, I use `pathFor "CompanyPage"`.

Am I missing something that is causing the incorrect url from the homepage? What js or html you need to have a look at? Let me know and I'll edit this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the correct link, you have to use the following syntax:

```
{{pathFor 'CompanyPage' _id=userId }}
```

Where this._id should be the user's id

What is happening:

For routes with appended identifier of some kind, Iron Router looks for the same identifier name in `this`. It would work if `this` is set to the correct data context, however in the case of your `/` route, you don't have a data context defined. On CompanyPage, the data context is defined to the correct user.

Comment: Hi that has not worked. Let me also state that the link's id is of the same as the jobpage. I have a link on that same page that goes to their job page. ie: `job/abcdefg`. Their profile link is also pointing to `company/abcdefg`. A conflict somewhere?

Comment: you have to replace the `this._id` to the userId.