# pathFor for iron router meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am pretty confused about this issue.
I have template which has two paths as follows:

```
Router.route('/companyDataManagement',{
        path:['/companyDataManagement','/companyDataManagement/:_id'],
        name: 'companyDataManagement',
        yieldTemplates:{
            'companyData':{to:'showCompanyData'},
            'companyDetails':{to:'showCompanyDetails'}
        }
});
```

This works perfectly fine. But how do I use `pathFor` for this template. 
`<a href="{{pathFor companyDataManagement}}">Click</a>` does not work

Comment: Have you tried to use two separate routes? One for each path?

Comment: How would that solve a problem?

Comment: What about `Router.route('/companyDataManagement/:_id',{` and then `<a href="{{pathFor companyDataManagement _id=this._id}}">Click</a>`. So essentially do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467393/meteor-with-iron-route-pathfor

Comment: And also look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30508647/1011724 regarding carlosccomp's 2 route suggestion

Comment: @Avishek gurung, I really don't know how it works in code, but perhaps the helper pathFor can't generate an url because he is not able to choose which path is the best pattern. It's just a guess (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if the companyDataManagement in the link is a name being passed from a helper or if you intend this to be the name of the route called? if it is the latter it needs to be encapsulated in single quotation marks like below

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'companyDataManagement'}}">Click</a>
```

If you want to then pass the :_id into the pathFor this comes from the data context which the link is in, if the data context does not supply the id you need to declare an object to pass into the template inside a helper:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    myContextHelper: function(){
        return {_id:'XXXXXXXXX'}
    }
});

{{#with myContextHelper}}
    <a href="{{pathFor 'companyDataManagement'}}">Click</a>
{{/with}}
```

Which should give you /companyDataManagement/XXXXXXXXX

You can also pass in the query, hash and data variables using for example query="q=1" or query=qstring where qstring is an object from a helper or a field in the myContextHelper object.

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'companyDataManagement' query=qstring }}">Click</a>
```

Additionally and not strictly to do with the question but is hopefully helpful, it looks from your code like you are just having the :id as an optional route part in your path and that the templates themselves do not require an :_id to be specified, in which case you can just use a ? to make the part optional:

```
path:'/companyDataManagement/:_id?',
```

You can also use this for your opening argument for the route to eliminate having to specify the path in the function:

```
Router.route('/companyDataManagement/:_id?',{
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if the above doesn't work happy to help troubleshoot if you can post a bit more of the code surrounding it

Comment: Very simple solution but made a big show in SO. Thank u guys. Let me close this issue. And yes, it was all about making "_id" optional.